# TT RGB Plus for ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, wine, fan

I recently purchased a set of 3 RGB fans from thermal take. They come with a software called TT RGB plus (https://ttrgbplus.thermaltake.com/). This software does not have a linux version, so I downloaded the exe and tried to run it with wine. This seemed to work at first until I realized that I could not change the color of the fans. Is it possible for me to be able to successfully run this software on Ubuntu?

Comment: How do they connect?  Do these have a USB interface?  I've seen linux software for Corsair products, I haven't looked for Thermaltake.

Comment: @rtaft I connected using the hub that came included, it had a USB 2.0 connector that i attached to my motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this [github project](https://github.com/chestm007/linux_thermaltake_riing), it may work for you.

Comment: Yeah it works great on arch linux (I'm running arch now), I never got it to work on Ubuntu for some reason though... :( Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Long due, but I found a project (Very awesome one indeed) that addresses multiple types of RGB compatible hardware devices.

This is the PPA:

`https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/openrgb`

Just run: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thopiekar/openrgb`

then `'sudo apt install openrgb`

Lastly run the app `openrgb`

And the project is:

https://gitlab.com/CalcProgrammer1/OpenRGB

Here are some examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This likely does not support the user's fans. I think I have the same ones, TT Riing Trio (TT RGB Plus). OpenRGB does not support them.

Answer (score 0):

i know it`s kind of old and you said you solved your problem. But i wanted to give my remedy for that situation, because it took me a while to solve that :)

My Thermaltake Fans and Light-Stripes are also connected via USB-Connectors direct on the Mainboard.

What i did was configurating a realy small (lite) Windows 10 in Virtualbox. I let this run in the background with the TT RGB Plus Software. With USB-Passthrough and the USB-Filter its working well and i can control the Fans and Lights and so on!

Of course it`s not the nicest way, but i can use Linux now as my First-OS and Windows 10 as Dual-Boot just for games. The Windows 10 Lite is not consuming much of Power.

O hope i could help someone with this. Because this problem was bordering me a lot :)

Greetings.